Spring Cloud Stream automatically register MessageChannel for Camunda
Demo project has deps:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

And just run in we can see in logs:
 INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel camundaBpmVersion_integrationflow.channel#0
    INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
    INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel camundaBpmVersion-out-0
   INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
   INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler camundaBpmVersion_integrationflow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
    INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
    INFO 75175 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageSource camundaBpmVersion-out-0_spca

How disable auto creating bind for Camunda and registration MessageSource?
But if add any empty consumer, this helps
@Bean
fun test() = Consumer<Any> {}


Try specify property spring.cloud.function.ineligible-definitions=camundaBpmVersion where test is the name of your function.
Basically your camunda auto-configuration has some functions as beans. Actually one bean, hence it is automatically registered. By adding your hack you creating a second function bean and without spring.cloud.function.definition the framework doesn't know what needs to be registered, so it registers nothing and your hack works. But it's a hack nevertheless. The spring.cloud.function.ineligible-definitions would be the correct way of solving it.

but (@Bean test) it just a hack in order to avoid creating binding

I think what Oleg means that you can just have spring.cloud.function.ineligible-definitions=camundaBpmVersion to skip that Camunda Supplier.

Yes, i think what is happening is that your camunda auto-configuration has some functions as beans. Actually one bean, hence it is automatically registered. By adding your hack you creating a second function bean and without spring.cloud.function.definition the framework doesn't know what needs to be registered. So, specify that bean via spring.cloud.function.ineligible-definition property and you shoul dbe fine.
